# Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store the value. Expected type is MySqlDateTime

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I get the following error while executing the below code.

> "Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <2015-02-14 11:26:07> in Purchase_Date Column.  Expected type is MySqlDateTime."

```
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
if (dt != null)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    // set the field values as required                
    dt.Rows.Add( textBox1.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value); /*error in this line*/
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` ?

Comment: dateTimePicker1.Value must be some data type that is not MySqlDateTime. My guess would be DateTime, but you will need to research it. Once you know the data type, you should look at the constructors and methods available in MySqlDateTime, to see if any of them will allow you easily convert from whatever type the dateTimePicker1.Value is. To get started [look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx). Then do a search [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=datetime%20to%20mysqldatetime%20c%23&rct=j)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type of value has a mismatch with column type Couldn't store <2015-02-27 16:49:13> in Purchase\_Date Column. Expected type is MySqlDateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765000/type-of-value-has-a-mismatch-with-column-type-couldnt-store-2015-02-27-16491)

Answer (score 0):

dateTimePicker1.Value is not equal to MySqlDateTime.
I think you should convert or cast your date picker to my sql date time.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```